# How to get crontab to run on the 6th, 7th and 8th business days of a month?

Tags: linux, cron, crontab, xquartz

I am building a cron expression that has to run every 30 minutes only on a range of business days, eg: 6th, 7th and 8th business days of a month.

Currently I have a cron expression but that only runs of 6th, 7th and 8th days of the month irrespective of it being business day or not.

Current cron expression:

```
0 0/30 * 6-8 * ?
```

I have tried using nearest business day expression

```
0 0/30 * 6W * ?
```

But it does not work for a range of days - like from **6W-8W**.

Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

P.S. Not looking to do it using a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can't (or at least I'm not clever enough to see how).

There are constraints in the crontab that allow you to pick *day of month* and *day of week*.

All business days would be day of week 1-5, but thats not enough because you need to count or express

> 6th, 7th, 8th day of (days-of-week:1-5) in this month

So you need a script.

```
$ cat /home/jaroslav/tmp/workday-567.sh
#!/bin/bash

jan01() { date +%s -d `date +%Y-01-01`; }
december() { echo $(($(jan01) + 365*24*3600)); }
day=`jan01`; december=`december`; 
today=${1:-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')}

this_months_678th=$(
while [ $day -lt $december ];do
    date '+%Y-%m-%d %B %A %u' -d@$day;
    let day=$day+86400; 
done  |
sort -u |
sed -e "/[67]$/d; /$(date '+%Y-%m')/!d" |
sed -n -e '6p; 7p; 8p'
)

if echo -e "$this_months_678th" | grep -q $today; then
    exit 0
fi
exit 1
```

November 2018;

```
$ for i in 2018-11-{01..31}; 
    do bash /home/jaroslav/tmp/workday-567.sh $i && echo run on $i;
  done 
run on 2018-11-08
run on 2018-11-09
run on 2018-11-12
```

Comment: How about use "6W" to get the next working day after the 6th; run a script to add a crontab "* */30 * ? * * * /script" entry and to add an entry to remove that crontab in 3 days time. Seems simpler. You can put a file in to /etc/cron.d/ rather than parse crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. No you can't. There is no way to specify a range of business days in a single cron expression. Cron expressions are limited to specifying fixed dates or intervals for the day of the month and day of the week fields.

One solution would be to create three separate cron jobs, one for each business day you want to run the command on, like this:

```
# for the 6th business day of the month
0 0/30 * * * [ $(date +\%a -d "$(date +\%Y-\%m-01) + 5 business day") = "Mon" ] && /path/to/your/command

# for the 7th business day of the month
0 0/30 * * * [ $(date +\%a -d "$(date +\%Y-\%m-01) + 6 business day") = "Tue" ] && /path/to/your/command

# for the 8th business day of the month
0 0/30 * * * [ $(date +\%a -d "$(date +\%Y-\%m-01) + 7 business day") = "Wed" ] && /path/to/your/command
```